# Slick-Util Library (LWJGL) rendering ttf fonts in 3d

Tags: java, lwjgl

I want to render ttf fonts for an overlay in a 3d game. The game is written in Java with the LWJGL Library. So I'm trying to learn how to use slick now. I got a workspace, the imports, a basic cube example and a String set up. I can get the String to render and can get the cube to render, but not both at the same time. I know I may be a noob, but I try to learn :) This is my code: http://pastebin.com/kbj2UNF0 I know its a bit messsed up because i tried a lot of stuff. Some comments are german.